# Does. exe setups work???

Tags: drivers

Does .exe setups work? On windows if I need a software I just download it from filehippo and install it but is it the same on Ubuntu.

Comment: On Ubuntu it is a .deb - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftwareManagement

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Comment: Also [look at this](http://askubuntu.com/a/321954/127327)

Comment: Since you tagged your question with “drivers”, are you asking about a device driver or a plain user application?

Answer (score 1):

No, `exe` files are not supported by Ubuntu. You can search for your desire application in Ubuntu Software Center and [install](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Software-in-Ubuntu) it if it is there or download the 'software package' directly from the [outside sources](http://www.howtogeek.com/142414/how-to-install-software-from-outside-ubuntus-software-repositories/)/internet. Have a loot at the "complete guide to software installation in Ubuntu" [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=781352) and of course the official [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware).

Answer (score 1):

Some .exe work only if you have WINE installed, which is an alternative environment where you can install executable windows program inside you Linux box. But before that, you need to have configured WINE properly in your Ubuntu system.